# Как правильно заказать и натянуть дизайн?

Tags: вёрстка, веб-дизайн

Я извиняюсь, но есть довольно глупый вопрос. У нас есть самописный сайт на php, с каким-никаким разделением представления от кода и нам нужно заказать дизайн. Собственно, вопрос - как осуществляется заказ дизайна? Что нужно передать верстальщику для того чтобы он натянул сам дизайн на сайт? Или этим должен заниматься разработчик бекэнда? Спасибо.

Comment: Расскажите ему, что должно быть на сайте. Сколько страниц, какие формы должны быть, кнопки, название сайта и прочее. Больше точностей ему скажете, лучше дизайн сделает, но основное, что должно быть на сайте сказать обязательно

Comment: А что за сайт? Вы уже выбрали дизайнера? Просто, я сам этим занимаюсь. Так что если хотите, обращайтесь. Контакты в профиле

Comment: @Yuri, спасибо, у нас несколько кандидатов есть, просто не хочется выглядеть совсем уже "лохами" как говорится.

Comment: user3416803, это понятно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, вопрос - как осуществляется заказ дизайна?
 - Составляете тз или заполняете бриф на разработку дизайна (этого добра навалом в интернете) где все прописываете и передаете верстальщику.
Что нужно передать верстальщику для того чтобы он натянул сам дизайн на сайт? Или этим должен заниматься разработчик бекэнда?
 - Верстальщику обычно передается PSD макем сайта. а он его превращает в HTML/CSS макет.
 - А натягивает дизайн обычно разработчик бекэнда.

PS. Все может сделать и сам верстальщик, если у него достаточно знаний в php